# Receving "500 Internal Server Error" on Post Request to Firebase-Cloud-Function Endpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, axios

I'm trying to make a `POST` request using `axios` to my firebase cloud-function on form `submit` in react app. But I get '`500`' error everytime I make a request with an html-page response ***This app works best with javascriot enabled.***

> Latest Update:
>
> It looks like there is no issue with cloud function
>   code. Rather more of a react-component issue. I used **Postman** to send
>   the `POST` request with header prop `Content-Type` set to `application/json`
>   and sending body in raw format `{"email": "example_email"}` and got
>   expected response from the cloud function. But when sent the request from
>   react component above, I get an html file response saying *the app
>   works best with javascript enabled*

I've tried setting `Content-Type` to both `Application/json` and `multipart/form-data` as I suspected it to be an issue but still got no luck.

Following is my code for cloud function and react submit form:

**Cloud Function**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true })

const runThisFunc1 = require(./libs/runThisFunc1);
const runThisFunc2 = require(./libs/runThisFunc2);

exports.wizardFunc = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

   cors(request, response, () => {
     let email = request.body.email;
     try {
       return runThisFunc1(email)
        .then(data => {
          console.log("Word Done by 1!");
          return runThisFunc2(data);
        })
        .then(res => {
          console.log("Word Done by 2!");
          return response.status(200).send("Success");
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error("Error: ", err.code);
          return response.status(500).end();
        });
     }catch(err) {
       return response.status(400).end();
     }
   });

});
```

**React-Form-Component Snippet**

```
import axios from 'axios'

...

handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const { email } = this.state
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUD_FUNCTION_ENDPOINT}`,
    data: { email: email },
    config: {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }
  })
    .then(res => {
      //do something with reponse here
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
    })
}

...
```

Is there something wrong I am doing in the code or the request config is wrong?

Comment: in the firebase dashboard => functions => logs. Check the error message. Filter by error. It should say what is the error is having. If you need more help, show us the log so we can help

Comment: have you tried logging out the value of `email` before sending it along with axios just to 100% make sure it's what you expect it to be?

Comment: @imjared, it looks like there is no issue with cloud function code. Rather more of a react-component issue. I used **Postman** to send the `POST` request with header prop `Content-Type` set to `application/json` and sending body in raw format `{"email": "example_email"}` and got expected response from cloud function. But when send request from react component above, I get an html file response saying _the app works best with javascript enabled_

Comment: are you using firebase-tools 7 ?